# spl-token create-token failed to create token

Tags: solana, spl, libssl

I am trying to create my first token using the Linode website
I created a Linux machine Ubuntu latest version
and I followed some steps to create my token
I used Solana blockchain for that, and I reached the part where we created the token

'''spl-token create-token'''

But I am getting an error : spl-token: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried 2 days almost every single in the internet, and I did everything I could to fix it, but I couldn't
I tried to repeat the steps from the beginning, didn't work
I tried to write using nano to source.list and install it manually, didn't work
I tried the older version of ubuntu.. nothing

Any help?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

So that version of libssl is not found in Ubuntu

check

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

for installed versions, either alias an existing installed version or install 1.1

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1 libssl-dev
```